# Is this how to deform an ellipse into a circle in complex analysis?

Tags: complex-analysis

Write down a function $z(s, t)$ deforming $\Gamma_0$ into $\Gamma_1$ in the domain $D$, where $\Gamma_0$ is the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{9}=1$ traversed once the counterclockwise starting from $(2, 0)$, $\Gamma_1$ is the circle $|z|=1$ traversed once counterclockwise starting from $(1, 0)$ and $D$ is the annulus $\frac12 \lt |z| \lt 4$ (hint: start with the parametrization $x(t)=2\cos2\pi t$, $y(t)=3\sin2\pi t$, $0 \lt t \lt 1$, for $\Gamma_0$).

The answer I came up with is $z(s, t)= (2-s)\cos2\pi t + i(3-\frac32s)\sin2\pi t$ when $0 \le s \le 2$ and $0 \le t \le 1$.
I thought this works because when $s=0$ we have the ellipse and as $s$ goes to $2$, it becomes the circle with radius $1$, but when I checked the answer key in my textbook it said:
$z(s, t)= (2-s)\cos2\pi t + i(3-2s)\sin2\pi t$ when $0 \le s$ and $t \le 1$.

I don't understand how the books answer deforms the ellipse into the circle with radius $1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(see figure below)

$$\tag{1}z(s, t)= (2-s)\cos2\pi t + i(3-2s)\sin2\pi t$$

(1) is what is sometimes called "morphing" between curves. It is made clearer when written under the vectorial form ($a+ib \ \longleftrightarrow \ \binom{a}{b}.$)

$$\begin{pmatrix}  (2-s)\cos2\pi t\\(3-2s)\sin2\pi t \end{pmatrix} \ \ = \ \  s \ \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}\cos(2\pi t)\\ \sin(2\pi t)\end{pmatrix}}_{circle} \ +\ (1-s)\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}2 \cos(2\pi t)\\ 3\sin(2\pi t)\end{pmatrix}}_{ellipse}$$

If you take $s=0,$ the circle disappears, it remains the ellipse.

If you take $s=1$, it is the inverse.

If you take intermediate values e.g. $s=\tfrac12$, you are in between the two curves.

[image]

Comment: Thank you that clears things up a lot. I had the $i$ on my paper just forgot to put it on my question