# Regular homotopy between a circle and an oval

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, complex-numbers, curves

How do I build a regular homotopy between an oval $$\frac{x^4}{a^4}+\frac{y^4}{b^4}=1$$ and a circle $$\
(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2=R^2$$?

I know I need to find parametrizations for both curves and there was a somewhat similar question discussed before [Is this how to deform an ellipse into a circle in complex analysis?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2212313/is-this-how-to-deform-an-ellipse-into-a-circle-in-complex-analysis). However, I still don't get where all this comes from and what exactly to do to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Won't the obvious 
$$\bigl(x-x_0(1-t)\bigr)^{2(1+t)}+\bigl(y-y_0(1-t)\bigr)^{2(1+t)}=(a^4b^4-R^2)t+R^2$$
for $t\in\{0,1\}$work?

Comment: Almost, you need to scale $x$ with $1-t+tb^4$ and similarly for $y$.

Comment: I mean the whole bracket containing $x$.

Comment: @Ennar could you explain why it's $$b^4$$ and not just b? I'm getting $$\frac{xb^4}{a^4}+\frac{ya^4}{b^4}=1$$ with $$b^4$$

Comment: @Meh Mech, I really meant scaling the whole bracket. If you scale just $x$, then you are correct that it should be $b$, not $b^4$.

Comment: @Ennar, sorry, took much time for me to type the formulas, hence I didn't see the whole bracket comment. Now it looks convincing. Thank you!